# Difference between $ and # in Linux environment

Tags: command-line, root, prompt

What is the difference between `$` and `#` signs in Linux environment? As I started working on Linux and I found that both are different. I mean do they have different set of privileges?

`[root@localhost ~]#` and `[tom@localhost ~]$`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In short, if the screen shows a dollar sign (`$`) or hash (`#`) on the left of the blinking cursor, you are in a command-line environment.

`$`, `#`, `%` symbols indicate the user account type you are logged in to.

- Dollar sign (`$`) means you are a normal user.
- hash (`#`) means you are the system administrator (root).
- In the C shell, the prompt ends with a percentage sign (`%`).

There are differences on prompts in different Unix or GNU/Linux distributions because of their default settings. For example, the prompt of Debian/Ubuntu is `guest@linux:~$`, the one of Fedora/CentOS/RedHat is `[guest@linux ~]$` and the one of SuSE Linux/OpenSUSE is `guest@linux:~>`. In general, the prompt usually show the login user name, machine hostname, and current working directory and ended with a dollar ($), percentage (%), or hash (#) sign.

```
guest@linux:~$
```

- `guest` - username: the user account you are logged in to.
- `linux` - machine hostname: the machine you are operating.
- `~` - current working directory: the directory you are in. Tilde (`~`) means home directory, i.e. the default directory when first logging in.

```
gayanw@myubuntu-host:~$ pwd
/home/gayanw
```

Reference: [wiki.debian.org.hk/w/Basic_Command_Line](http://wiki.debian.org.hk/w/Basic_Command_Line_(Eng))

Comment: @reverseiblean thanks for quik reply.Now i can see $ and # in centos promt.

Comment: for root user # and for tom or other users it is $

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti What does dollar sign do in this command `chattr +i "$(realpath /etc/resolv.conf)"` I found it on another question and I need clarification. Thanks.

Comment: @Shayan I don't think it makes sense. Just replace it with a path to an actual file like: `chattr +i /path/to/file`

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti It makes sense because `/etc/resolv.conf`  [was a symlink](https://askubuntu.com/q/863251/295286) in pre-systemd days to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` file.  Not entirely sure how it's used now, though. And `chattr` apparently doesn't work on symlinks

Comment: In fact, there's actually a [whole question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421980/85039) about it

Comment: So I understand `$` is used to denote variables.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Gayan Weerakutti answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/706190/1090198) here's a little mnemonic that helped me remembering the difference easily:

- $ = This is for the simple people working for money = Normal user
- # = This is for the wealthy, powerful people who do not need to work for money anymore, but rather work for status / likes / hashtags = Root user