# Is /etc/resolv.conf a symbolic link, and are changes to it persistent?

Tags: networking, internet, dns, hosts, resolvconf

Is `/etc/resolv.conf` a symbolic link? If so, how can one make persistent changes to the DNS?

Answer (score 4):

**No no no. You don't manually edit /etc/resolv.conf.**

To enter your own DNS addresses, go to the Network icon in the top panel, and select `Edit Connections`. Open the profile for the network where you'd like your own DNS servers defined.

Select the IPv4 tab. Set `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only`, and a comma-separated list of DNS servers into the `DNS servers` field.

[image]

Comment: @thank you for the information but I cannot use any kind of graphic interface. I have to do everything from the command line since I can only connect through ssh to the virtual machine and it is built in a way in which there is no GUI on it.

Comment: @yoyo_fun you should edit your question to include this very important information.

Answer (score 2):

With `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` you can see (due to the arrow and the linked file), that it is indeed a symbolic link. For your problem see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432026/linux-how-do-i-edit-resolv-conf) solution.

Comment: I'm not a clickybuntu user :P so I prefer the solution in the provided link!

Comment: Now that the OP has revealed that they're on a server with no GUI, your answer sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

I need to install the resolvconf package. It's a very strange case, maybe an install error or Ubuntu bug, but it happens in a fresh install.

Just do:

```
apt-get install resolvconf
```

Then:

```
service resolvconf restart
```

Or:

```
/etc/init.d/resolvconf restart
```

If you need to change de DNS, edit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base and add nameservers as:

```
nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver y.y.y.y
```

Then restart resolvconf.