# Ubuntu Prompt "$" Problems

Tags: command-line

Can someone tell me if this is normal for the `$` to move around or not?

While using Ubuntu 16.04 command line the `$` is at the directory name as it should be. However, when I change to any directory the `$`  then becomes part of the directory name at the end part of the directory name. How do I correct this new problem?

This is the root directory position -- `hallgroup@oldoffice:~$`

This is the position when I CD to any location -- `hallgroup@oldoffice:/usr$`

I just do not remember this being like this before. How do I correct this?

Comment: That looks like normal behavior. The default setting of the prompt shows your present working directory in the filesystem. You can change it in your .profile if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: What does that line mean?
Each of its component is significative. In fact, that line can be read as

```
UserName@HostName:FolderInHost$
```

The meaning of the symbol `$` and its other possible values are explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/706190/29595). Please have a careful read there.

Note also that `~` is not **root**, but it is just a shortcut for your **home** directory `/home/hallgroup`. This, as well as the `$` above, comes from Unix and it is the same in a lot of Unix-based environment (so MacOS too, for example).

The root is `/`, and it is not the home of any user.

If you `cd /` you will see that the folder part of the line changes to `/`.

With this in mind, it is clear that `hallgroup@oldoffice:~$` and `hallgroup@oldoffice:/usr$` are exactly the same thing, just telling you that you are in `/home/hallgroup` and in `/usr` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

As [user535733 told you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234310/ubuntu-prompt-problems/1234325#comment2077783_1234310), it is the default view, but you can customize it modifying the file in `~/.bashrc`.

In that file there is a line that is more or less like this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[01;34m\]\w\[\e[00m\] \$ '
```

To cut a long story short, it is telling you:

- write in bold green color (that is the escape code `\e[01;32m\]`) the username followed by a @ and then by the host name (`\u@\h`)
- put a double comma, then the current directory (in blue)
- at the end, put a dollar sign

If you change the line in the following way:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[00m\]: \$ \[\e[01;34m\]\w\[\e[00m\] '
```

you have moved the dollar sign. You can customize the string as you want, also adding time and date or a welcome message. As soon as you save the file (backup it before modification) perform the command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```