# Ubuntu_Terminal

Tags: 22.04

I am trying to run the command

```
sudo nix develop
```

which leads to the following output

```
warning: Using saved setting for 'extra-sandbox-paths = /opt' from ~/.local/share/nix/trusted-settings.json.
warning: Using saved setting for 'extra-substituters = https://nixbld.m-labs.hk' from ~/.local/share/nix/trusted-settings.json.
warning: Using saved setting for 'extra-trusted-public-keys = nixbld.m-labs.hk-1:5aSRVA5b320xbNvu30tqxVPXpld73bhtOeH6uAjRyHc=' from ~/.local/share/nix/trusted-settings.json.
root@SI-000072:/#
```

I am somewhat puzzled by the warning, since the folder ~/.local does not exist (I am aware that it is a hidden folder).
Since the command does not seem to finish correctly, does anyone have an idea how to deal with this warning?
And what is the meaning of

```
/#
```

in the last line?

```
root@SI-000072:/#
```

Thanks=)

Comment: For the second part of your question, see [Difference between $ and # in Linux environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706186/difference-between-and-in-linux-environment)

Comment: ... for the first part, are you sure it doesn't exist? remember that when you are logged in as root, `~` will likely equal `/root`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
2nd part: That clarifies it, thanks!
1st part: When I go to home/user/ and check ls -a then I do not see the .local folder

Comment: @steeldriver Aah, now I see what you mean. Yes, indeed when I am logged in as a root I do find the .local in /root with the above mentioned settings. Thanks!